# Issues With Tabular And Left-Side Spacing

Tags: tables, spacing, columns

I'm having an issue where my "Course Work" section, which is tabular, is offset by a space or two - whereas ever other section lines up perfectly. I've read up on the tabular environment but could only find information on adjusting spacing between columns and not before them.

This is my code and the output, with the red highlighting the undesired space:

[image]

```
\section{\textsc{Course Work}}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
 Molecular Biomechanics                & \ \ & Stem Cell Biology      & \ \ & Bioinstrumentation \\ 
 Eukaryotic Molecular Biology          & \ \ & Infectious Diseases    & \ \ & Biochemistry       \\
 Graduate Bioinformatics Seminar       & \ \ & Differential Equations & \ \ & Genetics           \\
 Undergraduate Research in MCD Biology & \ \ & Computational Biology  & \ \ & Statistics         \\
\end{tabular}
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

*I also apologize beforehand for using "blank columns" to adjust column spacing. I know it isn't the proper way to do that, but when my friend initially taught me some basic LaTeX that was how he did it and I just haven't felt the need to change it yet since learning more about the tabular environment.*

Comment: Try \hspace{-10pt} before the tabular environment,

Comment: Try `\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}`.  The two `@{}` suppress the column separation space at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: The two "@{}"s did the trick!

Comment: Your question would be improved if you pasted your code directly instead of including an image of it. Read the help about including code blocks.

Comment: Initially I had been inserting my code incorrectly so it wasn't showing up as a code block, but now it's been corrected and added. Thanks, Dan!

Comment: @Jesse - Rather than `\hspace{-10pt}`, it would be better to specify `\hspace{-\tabcolsep}`, as that's the amount of horizontal whitespace that's inserted to the left of the first column. (The default value of `\tabcolsep` is 6pt, not 10pt.) Even better, though, is to suppress the insertion of this amount of whitespace from the get-go, e.g., by following @nickie's suggestion to insert `@{}` before the specifier of the left-most column.

Comment: @Mico-- thanks for the insights :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}`. The two `@{}` suppress the column separation space at the beginning and at the end:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}
Molecular Biomechanics                & \ \ & Stem Cell Biology      & \ \ & Bioinstrumentation \\ 
Eukaryotic Molecular Biology          & \ \ & Infectious Diseases    & \ \ & Biochemistry       \\
Graduate Bioinformatics Seminar       & \ \ & Differential Equations & \ \ & Genetics           \\
Undergraduate Research in MCD Biology & \ \ & Computational Biology  & \ \ & Statistics         \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image: result]

BTW, instead of using empty columns for column spacing, you can use the same feature of tabular, e.g., add `@{\ \ }` or better `@{\hspace{1.5em}}` between your columns:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\hspace{1.5em}}l@{\hspace{1.5em}}l@{}}
Molecular Biomechanics                & Stem Cell Biology      & Bioinstrumentation \\ 
Eukaryotic Molecular Biology          & Infectious Diseases    & Biochemistry       \\
Graduate Bioinformatics Seminar       & Differential Equations & Genetics           \\
Undergraduate Research in MCD Biology & Computational Biology  & Statistics         \\
\end{tabular}
```